# does redis provide a client js library which can be included on html page using a script tag

Tags: javascript, redis

I am trying to implement a notification service using redis

I need a javascript library of redis which I can include in html and call the redis subscribe method to receive messages on a channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can using socket.io client for connect client

Comment: does socketio provide a js that can be included in a html using script tag?

Comment: I reckon by using socketio I will need a socketio server also.. Cant I connect to redis directly from client?